# Superscript registered mark '®' inside select menu

Tags: html, css, menu, superscript

Is is possible to have a superscript registered mark "®" inside a select menu? If so, how is this done? Can you use CSS to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to reword the question to simply "Is it possible to have a superscript character inside a select menu?".  The character to be superscripted is really irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to make a single character superscript inside an `<option>`.  You're stuck with a regular ® (`&reg;`).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve results in tough cases using this method to [superscript special characters with jQuery](http://adaldesign.com/web-development/superscript-special-characters-reg-jquery).
But I must admit that inside an option... I'm blank.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS1** : The numbers need tweaking depending on your font and point size.

```
<div style="font-size:96px;">
Registered<span style="vertical-align:2.7em; font-size:0.2em;">&reg;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible with CSS but in html you could write:

```
Company<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, <option>Company<sup>®</sup></option> does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this key shortcut for ®:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>